# cURL PHP Proper SSL between private servers with self-signed certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I originally had a connection between my 2 servers running with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to "false" with no Common Name in the SSL cert to avoid errors.  The following is the client code that connected to the server with the certificate:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
```

However, I recently changed this code (set it to true) and specified the computers certificate in PEM format.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,getcwd().'/includes/hostcert/Hostname.crt');
```

This worked great on the local network from a test machine, as the certificate is signed with it's hostname for a CN.  How can I setup the PHP code so it only trusts the hostname computer and maintains a secure connection.

I'm well aware you can just set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to "0" or "1" and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to "false", but these are not valid solutions as they break the SSL security.

My /etc/hosts file is as follows:

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost ExampleHostName
::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a certificate with a valid host name, *as requested by the client*. If you've used `machine.local` for your internal name, but now want to use external clients calling it via `machine.example.org`, then you need the certificate you use to be valid for `machine.example.org`.

If you need both (since the same machine may be called with different host names), use the Subject Alternative Name extension and put multiple DNS entries in your certificate.

Comment: So do I actually have to setup a DNS A record for this machines ip?

I'm running ArchLinux and I edited my question to show my "hosts" file, how should I modify it?

Thanks

Comment: DNS record or hosts file doesn't really matter, so long as it resolves to the correct IP address. What matters is the URL your client uses: the certificate must be valid for the host name in this URL.

Comment: Turns out I didn't even have to touch my hosts file.  Had to force SSL 3 though.

Comment: That's probably a different problem then. You should investigate it too: it's good to aim for TLS 1.0 and above nowadays (and pay attention to the cipher suites if using SSL 3/TLS 1.0, look up for "BEAST" mitigation).