# How to use a self signed certificate with XAMPP for HTTPS requests using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, https, xampp, ssl-certificate

I installed XAMPP and I need to test some HTTPS requests. First of all i tried to configure XAMPP so I can use the HTTPS requests.

This is what I did :

1) In the php.ini file , I uncommented the `openssl module`.

2) In the httpd.conf file , I uncommented the `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`

3) In the httpd-ssl.conf file , I redirected

`SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/ipm.crt"` and

`SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/ipm.key`" to my .crt and .key files.

4) I put my ipm.crt and ipm.key files in the apache folders `ssl.crt` and `ssl.key` inside XAMPP.

5) I created my self signed certificate by doing :

```
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -out ipm.csr -keyout ipm.pem

openssl rsa -in ipm.pem -out ipm.key

openssl x509 -in ipm.csr -out ipm.crt -req -signkey ipm.key -days 365
```

Now I am using a script to send an XML file. I am using cURL and my code is :

```
<?php
  /*
   * XML Sender/Client.
   */
  // Get our XML. You can declare it here or even load a file.


  $xml = file_get_contents("data.xml");


  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/cert/ipm.crt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/cert/ipm.pem');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD,'password');


  //I use this line only for debugging through fiddler. Must delete after done with debugging.
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');

  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ipv4.fiddler/iPM/receiver.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://ipv4.fiddler/iPM/receiver.php');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "Result = ".$ch_result;

  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  // Print CURL result.
?>
```

But I get this error back: `Curl error: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)`

However when I created my certificate I did put as a password the phrase: `password`

Any ideas on the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to specify `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'password');
```

Comment: Are you sure that the passphrase is correct? Try this: openssl rsa -in ipm.key. It will prompt you for the passphrase.

Comment: it gives me : -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- *many many characters like encoded* -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----    it didnt prompt me for something

Comment: What happens if you remove CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD and CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD from the script?

Comment: i get again the same error BUT i think i know where is the problem. when i use this : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/cert/ipm.crt'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/cert/ipm.pem');   first are these correct like this? i dont remember where i read to put it like this. And second where exactly are they pointing? I put my certificates in my project workspace in a folder called cert. Maybe the path is wrong?

Comment: because in the CURLOPT_CAINFO i use the .crt and in the CURLOPT_SSLCERT i use the pem. This seems a bit odd?