# 400 BAD REQUEST when using Nest API for Authorization

Tags: php, curl, nest-api

I am currently trying to use the Nest API but I can't get past the authorization part.
Here is the PHP code I use to call the API :

```
//access token url used for authorization 
$url="https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token?code=".$_GET['pin']."&client_id=".$api_key."&client_secret=".$secret_key."&grant_type=authorization_code"; 
$ch = curl_init ($url);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

//to have headers in response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
if($result){ 
    echo "Result : " .$result;
}else{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

And I get the following result for this call :

```
Result : HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST Content-Length: 0 Connection: Close
```

Is there other options I need to set in order to get it working?

EDIT : The generated url ($url) works fine with HTTPRequester (Firefox addon) so the problem comes most certainly from the curl request itself

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server (e.g. a request to load a web page) was somehow malformed therefore the server was unable to understand or process the request."

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to `false`? (I don't think it's directly relevant to the problem,  but it makes me curious.)

Comment: Also—is this all your code, or is there more later? Is anything else echoing below the curl_error echo you're showing in the question? I'm a little nonplussed by you apparently getting both a 200 and a 400 response.

Comment: @MattGibson This is almost all the code : the api key and secret are not shown here but that's all. Commenting the CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER or setting it to `true` gives me this error : `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`.

Comment: @ToasterChips In that case I would suggest you to create your own Certificate. Have a look at http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: @GauravDave I now have this error `error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: -home.nest.com.crt CApath: C:\wamp\www\testAPI\ajax`. I searched quickly what could be the problem but I didn't find relevant information.

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448815/how-to-make-an-https-request-using-curl

Comment: @GauravDave The call worked by executing the code on a server where I had set up https. That didn't exactly solve the problem using wamp but at least I get something working. Thanks a lot for the information!

Comment: Glad my suggestions helped you.

Comment: Note that Nest returns 400 bad request even if the request conforms to the HTTP spec and is just missing parameters required by the Nest API; you should check the response body nonetheless.

Comment: All the response was included in the result : the body for the call was empty.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Status codes

- 400 - Bad request - typically this occurs when a bad parameter is
  given to a method

So, try this:

```
echo $url;
exit;
```

before:

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
```

and copy paste that url to your browser address bar. See where you're posting wrong parameter.

See, if that helps.

Comment: Tried the request with the Firefox extension HttpRequester (since the request needs to be POSTed) with the generated url and I successfully receive a token. This means the problem comes from the curl part of the code, but where?

Comment: Add this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  to your code. Visit http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-03/0064.html. Might tell you where it is failing.

Comment: Adding this doesn't provide any additional information. Might be because there is no curl error with the call (I have a 200 code then a 400 in the response header)

Answer (score 0):

I think dev and inspect are running on same port. so remove the port and host for inspect on node by setting "inspect": false

*angular.json*

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "api:build",
    "inspect": false
  }
},
```