# codeigniter-restserver not working in https connection

Tags: authentication, https, codeigniter-restserver

I have created two codeigniter project subdomains.
In domain A I have kept only the controller and view part.
In domain B I have kept only the controller and model part.
I am using controller of domain A to send api calls to controller of domain B using cURL, then using the data sent from domain B to load in the view of domain A.
I have used codeigniter-restserver library by phil sturgeon and used basic authentication for the api authentication.
I am using IIS to host the services.
All the Get and Post request are working proper in this architecture. 
But when I enabled ssl in both the domains the api stopped working.
I tried changing the authentication type but it doesn't work with https.
I am not able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After 12 hours of searching for the problem, I found the answer in this post >>
[Make https request with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448815/how-to-make-an-https-request-using-curl)

Previously I was creating a curl http request which worked without ssl.